# How to run commerce_order_save() without triggering any rules?

Tags: 7, rules, commerce

I need to run `commerce_order_save()` on several Orders in loop but without triggering any Rules.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible, but the change would need to be sitewide (not just in the context of rules). You'd need to override the entity controller class used for commerce_product (which you could do with `hook_entity_info_alter()`), and re-implement its `save()` method so it doesn't invoke the entity hooks.

If that is undesirable (probably is), and you just need to update field values, you can use [`field_attach_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_update/7) instead, which will bypass the entity save process altogether:

```
$order->some_field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'foo';
field_attach_update('commerce_order', $order);
```

Other than those I don't think there's any way to accomplish it using the API.

Comment: I just need to update the content of a field and it needs to be saved in database. That's it.